Private props return unmodified or losing values within the class inside scope of child class method
So, I have two classes service-class & entity-class with private constructor & static async method, for creating new instance of class. My service-class create & call new entity-class instance and modified it with its properties.
Example | This is NOT NEST.JS code:
class Service {
   run() {
     const entity = Entity.createNewEntity(args);

     await entity.methodMother();

     const getMyProps1Back = entity.props1();

     // is [ ] empty array, not modified after methodChild
     console.log(getMyProps1Back);

   }
}

Each method of my entity is covered with bind decorator from npm: bind-decorator module
class Entity {
  this.props1! Array<Record<Type>>;
  this.props2 = new Map([]);


  private constructor(someArgs: any) {
     // some stuff
     this.props1 = [];  
  }

  get getProps1() {
    return this.props1;
  }

  static async createNewEntity() {
     const entity = new Entity();
     // blah-blah work here
     return entity;
  }

  @bind
  public async methodMother() {
    this.props1.push({ some: stuff });

    // 

    this.methodChild();
    // method logic
  }

  @bind
  private methodChild() {
     // adding more elements, or overwriting the array
     this.props1 = [test1, test2, test3];
  }
}

So my questions here are about explaining why context is lost during calling of methodChild within the methodMother and how is my getter return an unmodified array of props1?
## How does it work, and what should I do to avoid it?
Passing an array like argument and returning it back, like this? Or something else, like makign them anonymous?
  @bind
  private methodChild(props1 : Array<OfProps1>) {
     // adding more elements, or overwriting the array
     props1 = [test1, test2, test3];

     return arg;
  }


Does the code work when you remove @bind? What do you get when you console.log(this) in the bound methods?

I haven't tested it via console.log, but it seems it doesn't work with or without bind

Btw, you cannot have a getter and a property with the same name, and a getter wouldn't be called with .props1() but just .props1. Is this your actual code? Please provide a [mcve].

@Bergi it's just mistype, fixed, this is close-enough code

Close-enough is not good enough, we need something easily runnable that reproduces the problem. This does not run even with the most obvious syntax errors fixed.

Please share more of that "// method logic". I notice that methodMother is async, are you perhaps not properly waiting for the code to finish?

we will be able to provide some suggestions if you can share the code as a snippet over some live platforms

@Tayfun omw with that

@AlexZeDim are you going to [edit]?

The code you've sent seems to work fine without the @bind decorator (After some clean-up):
type KeyType = any
type ValueType = any

class Entity {
  props1!: Record<KeyType, ValueType>[];
  props2 = new Map([]);


  private constructor() {
    // some stuff
    this.props1 = [];
  }

  getProps1() { // <-- NOTE: Removed the `get` from here
    return this.props1;
  }

  static async createNewEntity() {
    const entity = new Entity();
    // blah-blah work here
    return entity;
  }

  public async methodMother() {
    this.props1.push({ some: 'stuff' });

    this.methodChild();
  }

  private methodChild() {
    this.props1 = [
      ...this.props1,// existing values

      { some: 'other stuff' },
      { evenMore: 'other stuff' },
      { andMore: 'other stuff' }
    ]
  }
}

And when you run it:
class Service {
  async run() {
    const entity = await Entity.createNewEntity();

    await entity.methodMother();

    const getMyProps1Back = entity.getProps1();

    console.log(getMyProps1Back);
  }
}

You get a nice Output:
[
  {
    some: "stuff",
  },
  {
    some: "other stuff",
  },
  {
    evenMore: "other stuff",
  },
  {
    andMore: "other stuff",
  }
]

This is based on the code you have given.

What you are looking at needs an explanation aimed at both ideas:

The clock is not actually misplaced inside methodChild. This has been
taken care of by the @bind decorator. That can't be the problem.

The real problem is in how you're modifying props1 in methodChild:

this.props1 = [test1, test2, test3];

And this line transfers the value of the original props1 array to a brand new Replacement an array, not just changing the existing one

Meanwhile, your getter getProps1 is likely returning a reference to
the original props1 array, which hasn't been modified:

get getProps1() {   return this.props1; }

This getter was defined before methodChild ran, so it's still pointing to the original (empty) array.


To fix this, you have a few options:

Modify the existing array instead of reassigning:
@bind
private methodChild() {
  this.props1.length = 0;  // Clear the array
  this.props1.push(test1, test2, test3);  // Add new elements
}


Update the getter to always return the current value of props1:
get getProps1() {
  return this.props1;
}


If you really have to reassign props1 then use a method instead
of a getter.
getProps1() {
  return this.props1;
}

Then call it asentity.getProps1() instead of entity.props1.


As for your suggestion of passing the array as an argument:
@bind
private methodChild(props1: Array<OfProps1>) {
  props1 = [test1, test2, test3];
  return props1;
}

This wouldn't solve the problem because JavaScript passes arrays by reference. Reassigning the parameter props1 inside the method won't affect the original this.props1. You'd need to do something like:
@bind
private methodChild() {
  const newProps1 = [test1, test2, test3];
  this.props1.length = 0;
  this.props1.push(...newProps1);
}

This modifies the existing array in place, ensuring that all references to this.props1 see the changes.

"This getter was defined before methodChild ran, so it's still pointing to the original (empty) array." - nope, that's not how getters work. The code is executed when the property is accessed, not when the getter is defined! Your suggestions to update the code of the getter make no sense, that's exactly the same code as the OP already has.
